# Overlap jar when run spark-submit

Tags: json, apache-spark, jar, spark-submit

I have spark job with `org.json`, but this lib is overridden by default jars of spark.

my spark job

```java
// init session
// System.out.println(Arrays.toString(org.json.JSONObject.class.getDeclaredMethods()));
```

If I run with `java -cp -\>`, this print `toMap()` method of `org.json.JSONObject.class`, but run with `spark-submit` does has.

my pom

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.json</groupId>
  <artifactId>json</artifactId>
  <version>20160810</version>
</dependency>
```

my jars:

```bash
longpt@xx:~$ ll /opt/spark320/jars/json*
-rw-r--r-- 1 x x  25475 Oct  6  2021 /opt/spark320/jars/json-1.8.jar
```

So what is the correct way to solve this problem?

If I remove `/opt/spark320/jars/json-1.8.jar` and run with `spark-submit` is correct, it print `toMap()` method.

I tried `--conf spark.jars.excludes=com.tdunning:json`, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.